# black and flake8 hooks conflicts

Tags: pre-commit-hook, flake8

Black fail and reformat the following

```
foo1 = foo2[len(foo3):]
```

to

```
foo1 = foo2[len(foo3) :]
```

But Flake8 fails with

```
foo1 = foo2[len(foo3) :]
```

and wants

```
foo1 = foo2[len(foo3):]
```

Unless I am mistaken, in this case Flake8 is right.

How to make a pre-commit that doesn't fail with black and flake8, in this case ?

Comment: black's docs cover this -- please read them

Comment: https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/the_black_code_style/current_style.html#slices ok, I see, we have to tell Flake8 to ignore E203 warning. But I have already extend-ignore = ["E203"] in [tool.flake8] part of pyproject.toml ... I wonder if  pyproject.toml is really taken into account by flake8?

Comment: flake8 does not yet support pyproject.toml.  the docs do not tell you to write in pyproject.toml do they? why would you do that if they don't tell you to?

Comment: the docs are not always up to date ... Our world is not perfect, like the humans who populate it ... Ok I'll use .flake8 file to put the flake8 configuration (I wanted to avoid scattering the configuration settings in several files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the answer of Anthony Sottile we can say that:

1- [Black wants extra space for “complex expressions” as foo1 = foo2[len(foo3) :] and this behaviour may raise E203 whitespace before ':' warnings in style guide enforcement tools like Flake8. Since E203 is not PEP 8 compliant, we should tell Flake8 to ignore these warnings.](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/the_black_code_style/current_style.html#slices)

2- Contrary to what I thought, the pyproject.toml file is not used for the configuration of flake8. [We must absolutely and exclusively use .flake8, setup.cfg, or tox.ini.](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/configuration.html#project-configuration)

Finally, here is the configuration that I use (and which fix the issue encountered initially):

```
$ more .pre-commit-config.yaml
repos:

-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
    rev: v4.4.0
    hooks: # general hooks
    -   id: check-added-large-files
    -   id: check-ast
    -   id: check-case-conflict
    -   id: check-docstring-first
    -   id: check-json
    -   id: check-merge-conflict
    -   id: check-toml
    -   id: check-xml
    -   id: check-yaml
    -   id: debug-statements
    -   id: end-of-file-fixer
    -   id: fix-encoding-pragma
    -   id: name-tests-test
    -   id: trailing-whitespace

-   repo: https://github.com/psf/black
    rev: 23.1.0
    hooks: # code formatter
    -   id: black
        language: python
        args: ["--line-length=79"]

-   repo: https://github.com/pycqa/isort
    rev: 5.12.0
    hooks: # imports sorting
    -   id: isort
        name: isort (python)

-   repo: https://github.com/econchick/interrogate
    rev: 1.5.0
    hooks: # documentation checker
    -   id: interrogate
        args: [--fail-under=80, -vv]

-   repo: https://github.com/PyCQA/flake8
    rev: 6.0.0
    hooks:
    -   id: flake8
        name: flake8 under python3
        language_version: python3

$ more pyproject.toml
[tool.black]
line-length = 79
include = '\.pyi?$'
exclude = '''
/(
    \.git
  | \.hg
  | \.mypy_cache
  | \.tox
  | \.venv
  | _build
  | buck-out
  | build
  | dist
)/
'''

#[tool.flake8]
#max-line-length = 79
#exclude = [".git", "__pycache__", "dist"]
#extend-ignore = ["E203", "E266", "E501", "W503", "F403", "F401"]
#max-complexity = 10

[tool.isort]
atomic = true
profile = "black"
line_length = 79
skip_gitignore = true

$ more .flake8
[flake8]
ignore = E203, E266, E501, W503, F403, F401
exclude =
    .git,
    __pycache__,
    docs/source/conf.py,
    build,
    dist
max-complexity = 10
max-line-length = 79
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is discussed [here](https://github.com/PyCQA/pycodestyle/issues/373#issuecomment-760190686) and is the problem of old flake8.
I updated the version of flake8 to the latest one and it worked for me.